# Error in running the command $ dse gremlin-console -i test.groovy

Tags: groovy, graph, gremlin, datastax-enterprise-graph

I came in to a situation in which I have to run a bash script lets say testbash.sh has the following lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
 dse gremlin-console -i test.groovy
```

test.groovy file contains:

```
:remote config alias g cord.g
 schema.describe()
```

The output of bash script testbash.sh is below

Error in /home/nithin/test.groovy at [2: schema.describe()] - No such property: schema for class: groovysh_evaluate.

Any clue will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't seem to recreate your problem (at least on the latest version of 5.1.x). To troubleshoot, I think that you should first start `dse gremlin-console` without the `-i` and paste the commands from the script into the console and make sure that they return properly. If you get the same error, then you know that you can start looking into the problem from there without worrying about `-i` at all. Is `cord.g` initialized with a graph for a schema to be present?

If the commands work fine, then there must be something wrong with the console bootstrap that initializes it to work with the server on startup. The bootstrap script should be present in your DSE installation and is called `dse-init.groovy`. I would try pasting you commands into the bottom of that script and seeing if that solves your problem. If it does, then perhaps you have an older version of DSE because I do recall some changes in recent months for `-i` and `-e` handling that perhaps are related. I think that editing `dse-init.groovy` could be a reasonable workaround for you if you aren't able to upgrade for some reason.

Comment: Without -i option, I am not getting any errors. Just work as $ dse gremlin-console command.

Comment: sorry - i don't follow exactly what you tried. do you mean you edited the bootstrap script and then used `dse gremlin-console` and it worked? or are you just saying that `dse gremlin-console` worked?

Comment: oh - hmm - what version of DSE is that? On an older version that approach might make sense.....not sure if that syntax is supported on newer versions.

Comment: yes - i would think that on 5.1.0 you might have that problem. i tested on 5.1.9 (don't think that's released yet) and it all worked fine. i think you just need to upgrade.

Comment: The issue is resolved. When i tried the same on dse 5.1.2 worked fine.Your answer really helped me.

Comment: glad its working - please "accept" the answer since it's all good now. thanks